# Как проверить значение в массиве

Tags: php

Есть цикл:

```
foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) {
    echo $attribute_group['name'];
    foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) {
        echo $attribute['name'];
        echo $attribute['text'];
    }
}
```

я знаю что в массиве `$attribute_group`, как мне проверить значение `$attribute_group['name']` **до** цикла? Например нужно условие `if ($attribute_group['name'])` то делать одно, если нет то другое и т.д. Я знаю что массив `$attribute_group` объявляется в цикле, но как мне получить `$attribute_group['name']` до этого цикла? Отдельный цикл? Подскажите тогда как правильно это реализовать, спасибо.

> Обновил вопрос

В общем решил в цикле проверять условие, **вот как хочу сделать**

```
<?php if($attribute_groups) {  ?>
            <?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
              <?php if ($attribute_group['name']=='Технические характеристики') { ?>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-harakter">
                    <table class="table">
              <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
               </table>
            </div>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <p>Технические характеристики отсутствуют</p>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($attribute_group['name']=='Документы') { ?>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-doc">
                    <table class="table">
              <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
               </table>
            </div>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <p>Документация отсутствует</p>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($attribute_group['name']=='Сертификаты') { ?>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-sertif">
                    <table class="table">
              <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
               </table>
            </div>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <p>Сертификаты отсутствуют</p>
              <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Но выводит на странице некорректно, пеняю на то что неправильно делаю проверку в цикле, подскажите что не так?

Comment: Не очень корректная постановка вопроса. Учитывая, что `$attribute_group` является элементом `$attribute_groups` значений `$attribute_group['name']` будет несколько. Какое из них вы хотите проверить? Если каждое, то только в цикле, если какое-то определенное `$i`-е (например первое), то обращайтесь напрямую по индексу `$attribute_groups[$i]['name']`

Comment: нет, мне нужно каждое `$attribute_group['name']`, в зависимости от этого значения я вывожу соответствующую информацию, но мой цикл динамичный и поэтому значений `$attribute_group['name']` может и не быть, так вот у меня не получается сделать так. Приду домой немного конкретизирую вопрос.

Comment: Да, вопрос необходимо конкретизировать.

Answer (score 2):

Если заранее известно значение которое необходимо проверить, то можно так:

Значение которое проверяем: 'testValue';

```
foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { 
    if(  in_array('testValue', $attribute_group)  )
        // Делаем что tо 
    }
}
```

Comment: ваш способ не подходит, т.к. массив `$attribute_groups` является массивом массивов

Comment: Вы этот код пишите в начале первого foreach. И все будет работать. Только не "$attribute_groups" как у меня написано, а "$attribute_group"

Comment: я попрвавил код

Comment: ну вообще изначально была необходимость проверить значение до цикла, этот код не решает этой проблемы, да и чем `in_array` отличается от простой проверки значения, типа `$attribute_group['name']=='Сертификаты'` по поведению так и не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Пример, по смыслу близкий к вашему коду:

```
<?php $attribute_groups = [
        ['name'=> 'group 1', 'attribute'=>['name'=>'attr1', 'text'=>'some text 1']],
        ['name'=> 'group 2', 'attribute'=>['name'=>'attr2', 'text'=>'some text 2']]
    ] ?>

<?php foreach($attribute_groups as $attribute_group): ?>

<!--    проверим для примера, является ли элемент name пустым-->
    <?php if(!empty ($attribute_group['name'])){?><!--if-->

        <!--если да, то-->

        <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $attribute; ?></td> <br/>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>


    <?php } else { ?><!--else-->
        <!-- если нет, то-->


    <?php } ?><!--endif-->

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь правильно понял задачу. До какого цикла вам нужно обработать **name**? И зачем вам вообще там цыкл? Можете добавить в вопрос тестовые данные для **$attribute_groups**

```
<?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) : ?>
    <p><b><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></b></p>
    <?php if($attribute_group['attribute']['name']): ?>
        <!-- Тут что-то делаем -->
    <?php endif;?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Возможно на входе здесь структура - массивы в массиве с конечными элементами.
2. При отладке структуры не следует усложнять код, а заранее отладить её модель.
3. В ВИД-ах функция "foreach(массив as ключ=>элемент) {}" прописывается:

   элемент) : ?>
4. Это же правило относится и к оператору условия:
   "  "

Answer (score -3):

Чтобы получать независимые значения элементов массива внутри цикла `foreach`, в его параметрах задаётся ключ элемента, к примеру, под именем `$key`,  т.е.

```
<?php
 foreach ($attribute_groups as $key =>$attribute_group) {
```

//- Код с использованием $key, $attribute_groups[$key],  $attribute_group и других любых массивов

```
}
```